# Help evaluating this limit

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{\alpha\to\omega}-\frac{\alpha r_0}{\omega(\omega^{2}-\alpha^{2})}\sin(\omega t)+\frac{r_0}{\omega^{2}-\alpha^{2}}\sin(\alpha t)=\frac{r_0}{2\omega^{2}}sin(\omega t)+\frac{r_0}{2\omega}t\sin(\omega t)$$

This limit came up in my introduction differential equations class when going over resonance. I just don't know how they were able to solve this limit. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you have written the formulas correctly? Maybe there should be some minus at some place in the left-hand side. And a cosine instead of a sine in the last term (depending on what you change of course).

Comment: I changed a minus sign in the front shouldn't be an equal sign does that help? That was a typo on my part sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit we want to calculate is

> $$\lim_{\alpha\to\omega}-\frac{\alpha r_0}{\omega(\omega^{2}-\alpha^{2})}\sin(\omega t)+\frac{r_0}{\omega^{2}-\alpha^{2}}\sin(\alpha t)
> $$

Here is a **hint**:

Do partial fraction decomposition on
$$
\frac{\alpha r_0}{\omega(\omega^2-\alpha^2)}\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{r_0}{\omega^2-\alpha^2}.
$$
You will get, among other things, terms that looks like difference quotients for sine. If you know that 
$$
\frac{d}{d\omega}\sin(\omega t)=t\cos(\omega t)
$$
then you are almost done. Can you take it from here?

**Added**

Let me add the correct formula. It is

> $$\lim_{\alpha\to\omega}-\frac{\alpha r_0}{\omega(\omega^{2}-\alpha^{2})}\sin(\omega t)+\frac{r_0}{\omega^{2}-\alpha^{2}}\sin(\alpha t)
> =\frac{r_0}{2\omega^2}\sin(\omega t)-\frac{r_0}{2\omega}t\cos(\omega t).
> $$

Comment: Thanks will work on when home if you have the time could you show steps blacked out to reference later.